# Any collection object to hold list of combination of more than 2 elements?

Tags: java, arrays, list, collections, element

Is there a collection object or a approach to hold a combination of elements?

For instance, I need to create a list that contains the combination of the elements name, age, height and weight.

Creating an object for this is not a good idea in my case. Because the number of fields keep changing.
I need to create this list to pass to a query.

Any solution?

Comment: The number of elements name, age, height and weight are changing? What makes them so iradically changing that makes any combination of a list in a list or a quiet flexible class to store all these elements and beeing and that stuffed in a list impossible? I'm afraid there is more information about what you are trying to code to make actual sugestions since you ruled out a list of objects.

Comment: Yes, sometimes it could be 3, 4 or even 2. So not always 4 elements.

Comment: Then the next question is what you want you do with these elements. Meaning how to you plan to adress them for further use. Are there any reasons speaking against a list(or any collection of your liking) filled with maps so you use as key what information your a trying to store and as value the actual information. Even tho i'd prefer to make a class with variables for the maximum amount of elements and use null or an empty String or whatever you like as note that this attribute isn't used for the person in question.

Comment: I need to build a query using that combination of elements.

Comment: Well i guess you could always use a List<List<Object>> and then with some combination of instanceOf or getClass and switch case use those contents however you like. But i don't think that sort of code would be all too pretty.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
class MyContainer {
  String someString;
  int someInt;
}

List <MyContainer> myList = new List<>();
```

Something like that!?

I don´t know exactly, what you mean by "Creating an object for this is not a good idea in my case". You could as an alternative create a `List<Object>` and put in whatever you have or even a `List<List<Object>>` if you want to have a List of a number of grouped objects.

Comment: Sometimes I need 3 elements, or 4 elements like that.

Comment: Only multiple different elements? Then use List<Object>! Or something similar to List, there are various...

Comment: How do you hold something like List<String, String, Integer, Long>?

Comment: You would use a List<List<Object>> but you wouldn't know for instance when querying which belong to which (an int could be age or height for instance).  Your best bet is to really just make an object, like @luk2302 suggests, and allow some fields to be null if they're not required.

Comment: One other way would be to make a List<List<Object>> and specify before each element which type it is for example "String", "hi", "int", 7, "float", 3.145f or String, "hi", Integer, 7, Float, 3.145f - But that is not pretty nor effective.

Comment: Though this is not the best fit, I guess this is the closet I can get.

Answer (score 1):

The best approach would be to make an Object with all the possible elements in it.

```
class myObject {
     String name;
     Integer age;
     Float weight; 
     // Etc
}
```

Or have a base class then have another class which extends this with additional elements

```
class myExtendedObject extends myObject{
     String streetAddress;
     String city;
     // etc;
}
```

Then if you don't have an element set it to null... you could always build your query from the object itself by including a method to return your query, juct check if its null and not include in your query (Assuming you mean an sql style query)

```
public String buildQuery{
     String query = "Select * from blahtable Where ";
     query += (name != null)?" name = " + name : "";

     // etc, or what ever your query needs to be
     return query
}
```

Other wise you could just have a method which returns a map of your elements then you know what the type of each element is based on the key

```
 public Map<String, Object> getElements{
      Map<String, Object> myMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
      if(name != null)
         myMap.put("Name", name);

      // etc
      return myMap
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

What about just using a Map for that and use attribute name as key (e.g. Weight )?
You can use any combination of attributes you want and it would be convenient to pass such collection to the query

Consider [Enum map](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/EnumMap.html) should you require more column names type safety